# Recaptcha detects PhantomJS

Tags: c#, selenium

When i use PhantomJS through Selenium for get the recaptcha V2 challenge (Answers and pictures to choose ) the challenges are harder than a classic brower ( Chrome or Firefox for example ) ...

How Recaptcha arrived to detects PhantomJS ?

My code :

```
        PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
        options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);

        PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://deathbycaptcha.com/");
        Console.WriteLine("Page ouverte");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("undefined")));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class=recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark]")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        lock(lockThis){
            driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("screeno.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Screen realise")
```

Some ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing fiddler and compare the headers being sent in your program versus a standard browser http://www.telerik.com/fiddler .

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the user agent when using PhantomJS.